# Undefined index: code use Export to Excel in Laravel 5.8

Tags: excel, laravel, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm executing  Export, Import to Excel in Laravel. But I have an error

> Undefined index: code

in a file  **AlumniImport.php**.
Thank you for help!

**AlumniImport.php**

```php
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class AlumniImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'code'          => $row["code"],
            'first_name'    => $row["first_name"],
            'last_name'     => $row["last_name"],
            'username'      => $row["username"],
            'password'      => Hash::make($row["password"]),
            'tel'           => $row["tel"],
            'email'         => $row["email"],
            'gender'        => $row["gender"],
            'birthday'      => $row["birthday"],
            'address'       => $row["address"],
            'status_id'     => $row["status_id"],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**AlumniController.php**

```php
// Excel
use App\Imports\AlumniImport;
use App\Exports\AlumniExport;
use Excel;
class AlumniController extends Controller
{
 public function import()
    {
        Excel::import(new AlumniImport,request()->file('file'));
        return back();  
    }
}
```

Example of data in Excel:

```
code    first_name  last_name   username    password    tel     email      gender birthday  address status_id
B8888   John        Smith       johnsmith   123456    123456    johnsmith@gmail.com Male 4/9/1998   USA 1 
B7777   Tom         Cruise      tomcruise   123456    123456    tomcruies@gmail.com Male    4/5/1998 Canada 1 
B6666   Lena        Do          lenado      123456    123456    lenado@gmail.com    Male    9/4/1997    USA 2
```

Comment: is there a column "code" in your excel file ? do you have headers in the first line of your excel ? would be easier if you provided a sample of the excel file in question.

Comment: Sure,
Row 1: **code,first_name,last_name,username,password,tel,email,gender,birthday,address,status_id**
Row 2: 
**data of row1 **
Row 3:
** data of row2**

Comment: Please post the whole error that you're getting and the example excel file on which it is failing.

Comment: If I comment little hard read, I'm sorry because I'm a new contributor.

Comment: I get error's: Undefined index: code.
And file alumnies_db.xlsx
**code first_name last_name username password tel email gender birthday address status_id**
_B8888 John Smith johnsmith 123456 123456 johnsmith@gmail.com Male 4/9/1998 USA 1_
_B7777 Tom Cruise tomcruise 123456 123456 tomcruies@gmail.com Male 4/5/1998 Canada 1_
_B6666 Lena Do lenado 123456 123456 lenado@gmail.com Male 9/4/1997 USA 2_

Comment: You can [edit] your question and include additional info there

Comment: Here link of file alumnies.xlsx : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VQv-KYzF52BTXvssQrX23TP_MbXG6ttl)

Answer (score 2):

You can confirm my suggestion by doing a `var_dump($row);die();`

what i found on the package Maatwebsite, the `$row` has numeric indexes.

try this

```
class AlumniImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'code'          => $row[0],
            'first_name'    => $row[1],
            'last_name'     => $row[2],
            'username'      => $row[3],
            'password'      => Hash::make($row[4]),
            'tel'           => $row[5],
            'email'         => $row[6],
            'gender'        => $row[7],
            'birthday'      => $row[8],
            'address'       => $row[9],
            'status_id'     => $row[10],
        ]);
    }
}
```

-----edit-----

dont forget to put the fields in the `$fillable` of the `User::class`

```
class User extend Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['code','first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'password', 'tel', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday', 'address', 'status_id'];
    .....
}
```

if you dont wanna put these fields as fillable and i dont recommend you to do it (especially for the password field) you can do it this way;

```
class AlumniImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->code = $row[0];
        $user->first_name = $row[1];
        $user->last_name = $row[2];
        $user->username = $row[3];
        $user->password = Hash::make($row[4]);
        $user->tel = $row[5];
        $user->email = $row[6];
        $user->gender = $row[7];
        $user->birthday = $row[8];
        $user->address = $row[9];
        $user->status_id = $row[10];
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you suggestion, but now I get this error: **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'code' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-07-18 12:09:45, 2019-07-18 12:09:45))**

Comment: @RusKhanh did you set the `protected $fillable` in the `User::class` model ?

Comment: Yep, when I input follow your suggestion is Add `var_dump($row) or die();`, I get the data in my file data.xlsx. But, why I can't import data.
Data return from var_dump($row) above:
_array(11) { ["code"]=> string(5) "B7777" ["first_name"]=> string(4) "John" ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Smith" ["username"]=> string(9) "johnsmith" ["password"]=> float(123456) ["tel"]=> float(123456) ["email"]=> string(15) "johnsmith@gmail" ["gender"]=> string(4) "Male" ["birthday"]=> float(32755) ["address"]=> string(3) "USA" ["status_id"]=> float(1) }_

Comment: @RusKhanh i've added an alternative in my solution, check the edit

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much @N69S

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your `AlumniImport` class:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
```

After this, include `WithHeadingRow` in your `AlumniImport` class like this:

```
class AlumniImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
```